# Deploy enterprise app on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, ejb

I want to know if google app engine supports EJB injection. I did not find any documentation explain this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems EJB injection is not supported:

> There are various APIs and technologies that are not supported by App Engine at present for various reasons. These include:
>
> Enterprise Java Beans (EJB)

See [here](http://page2rss.com/c/28d80649286a663b3ccf3736c8c74f26/7304397_7305889/) for more info.